# Odd characters showing up in symbology view

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, fields-attributes, table

I am trying to symbolize based on company name but there are weird Greek symbols showing up in my Symbology view of the actual field values. Has anyone ever had this problem? The weird symbols do not show up in the Table View.

[image: Screenshot of Symbology view]

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the version of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using, please?  Also, you say that the Table View shows nothing but could you include a screenshot from the Attribute Table of this layer showing one or more cells that these values are emanating from, please?